# Parsing JSON data using jQuery

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I would like to parse some JSON data but am not sure what I am doing wrong.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
$.getJSON('bd/getuserDetails',userID,function(data) {
    $.each(data.UserDTO,function(index, value){
         alert(value);
    });
});
```

In my Java action class I am populating `UserDTO` with relevant details like
name, age, etc.

The above code is able to parse my object, but my intentions are to access the value based on the name like `alert(value.name);  //user name`.  Currently it's parsing and displaying the values but I am not able to determine the name for the given value.

How can I access the collection with the name for the corresponding value?

Comment: can you add information that you receive in data variable? before $.each statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$.getJSON('bd/getuserDetails',userID,function(data) {
    $.each(data.UserDTO,function(key, value){
         alert(key + ' : ' + value);
    });
});
```

Suppose if your `data.UserDTO` is like:

```
data.UserDTO = {'name' : 'one', 'title' : 'Mr', ..};
```

then in above loop:

```
key => name, title...

value => one, Mr...
```

#### But

if your

```
data.UserDTO = [ {'name' : 'one', 'title' : 'Mr', ..}, 
                 {'name' : 'two', 'title' : 'Mrs', ..} 
               ];
```

then above loop:

```
key => 0,1... (index of each object within that array)

value => {'name' : 'one', 'title' : 'Mr', ..}, {'name' : 'two', 'title' : 'Mrs', ..} ...
```

Comment: that's perfect will do my job to maximum.Thanks i was missing this key part ;)